# WordPress on shared server Plugin not working

Tags: plugins, iis

I have hosted one site on production server IIS using the shared hosting of the physical file(source code). The problem is that Modern Events Calendar plugin is not working when I am using the shared hosting.

Locally it's working fine on my PC because I am not using their shared hosting I am using the D drive path.

Any idea how to solve this issue!

IIS 8.5
WordPress site
MySQL

Comment: You need to be more specific about "is not working." Is it not showing up at all? Throwing an error? Have you enabled `wp-debug` to see what shows up?

Comment: On website its is showing "skin controller doesnot exist". Calendar not showing on website and yes i opened wp-debug true but no error even i checked the php errors.
The error is due to the location of source code if in IIS i select the source code from a shared server it is not showing this plugin but if i select the source code from D drive or any drive which ever has the source code in that case its working fine.
But i need to run it by selecting the shared server path.

Comment: @KennethOdle i did one thing in the wp-config.php
i write define ('WP_PLUGIN_DIR','D:/Website/www/wp-content/Plugins');
once i did this it start working fine but after couple of refresh all plugins auto deactivated .